# Margin (top-bottom) for DIV into another DIV

Tags: html, margin, outer-join

recently I work on a little project.

THe page is simple, it has a header and a main content section

The header is represented as a background div and has background-image. However this div also includes another div in it which contains some text, this div  has a Background-color, which is 0.5 transparent

What I intend to do is to make top and bottom margins for this inner div, in order to make a space between the top and bottom edges of outer div and inner div.

But when I do so, the top margin causes to make margin not for inner div but outer and the top section is filled with white color, it means that both divs get margin.

Padding is useless I think as my inner div has a background color and it will stratch inner div.

Code: [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VqA7/)

```
<div id="top" class="bg-fixed">
    <div id="about_text">some text</div>
</div>

<style>
        #about_text {

            width: 400px;
        height: 100%;
        font-size: 15px;
            color: #ffffff;
        line-height:normal;
        text-align: justify;
        margin-left: 800px;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
   background: rgba(34, 39, 41, 0.4);
   border-radius: 30px 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px; 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.7)

        }

.bg-fixed {
    background-image:url(../images/back.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    }

</style>
```

Please help with this issue.

Comment: padding will stretch the outer div not the inner div. padding on the outer div would have been my answer. the box model is content+padding+border+margin. so if you apply padding to the outer div this will not "stretch" the inner div.

Comment: So you mean that paddin on outer div will help?? I will give a try as soon as possible.. Thank you